# Save commands sent over to the gnuplot program by Gnuplot-py package

Tags: python, gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot. I am using Unix.

I see the commands/error and their output on the terminal but I want to save them on a file too for storage purposes.

There is a save command in gnuplot but it only saves the last plot or splot command given by  the module and the final settings.

Suppose I plot a line with settings 'A' and after doing some calculation I went and re-plotted another line with setting 'B'

gnuplot.save() command would only save the last command and the latest settings. How can I save all the issued commands?

Kindly help...

Comment: You could use matplotlib to make your plots entirely in python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not extremely familiar with gnuplot-py -- but if it writes the commands to the terminal as it executes them, you can just use shell redirection:

```
python myPythonScriptWithGnuplot.py > commandfile.gp  #redirect stdout
python myPythonScriptWithGnuplot.py 2> commandfile.gp  #redirect stderr
```

Of course, this won't help if you're writing other things to the terminal from python ...

But note that gnuplot-py sends the data to gnuplot via a temporary FIFO (I think anyway).  So, if you're plotting data (e.g. lists, numpy arrays, etc ... not functions like `"sin(x)"`), when you try to plot the data, the FIFO will have been purged from your system and your plot command will fail complaining it can't find the datafile.

**EDIT**

After a (quick) look at the source, it appears you have a few options.  Your first option:  pass `debug=1` to the constructor (You already might be doing this).  This will cause the commands to be written to standard-error.  with a little (or a lot) of shell magic, you can separate out the different output streams.  Here's a recipe to put stderr from a command into a file while still leaving the output on your terminal that works in bash (I'm using bash 4.1.5 -- but I'm pretty sure this has been around for a while):

```
((command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ) | tee command_stderr.log ) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
          #swap stderr/out  
                             #tee puts data in output file and to terminal
                                                      #swap stderr/stdout again.
```

(I'd love to see a cleaner way to do this output stream swapping if anyone knows it...)

Alternatively, you can pass a filename to the `Gnuplot` constructor.  This will write the commands to that file.  As far as I can tell, there's no method to allow you to write the commmands to the file and to the gnuplot pipe.  However, you can always start up multiple `Gnuplot` instances and write the commands to a file via the main instance and then whenever you write a plot command, tell the second instance to `load "filename"`.  Of course, if you use this method, you should probably specify that the data should be `inline`d.

A third option is to abandon gnuplot-py in favor of pyGnuplot since I'm still actively developing that one -- Then if something doesn't work, or you'd like to have a feature added, you can just let me know ;)

Comment: Redirection will work but i also want to show my results on the terminal too.

Comment: @varun : I've edited with a way that you can manipulate the output streams so that it will *hopefully* leave the commands on the terminal, but also put them into a file for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Non-python answer would be to use `script' command.